C# Code is not working without breakpoint on unity
I'll start by saying that I'm working on Unity, I need to manage the menu input in the Oculus controller but every time I press the button it only works that time and that's it. If I set breakpoints it works every time
public void Update()
{
    if (menu.activeSelf == true && smenu.activeSelf == true)
    {
        menu.SetActive(false);
        smenu.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (menu.activeSelf == true && amenu.activeSelf == true)
    {
        menu.SetActive(false);
        amenu.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (menu.activeSelf == true && imenu.activeSelf == true)
    {
        menu.SetActive(false);
        imenu.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Menu) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
    {
        
        ToggleMenu();
        Debug.Log("Pause menu ON");
        
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.JoystickButton3) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.JoystickButton1)) 
    {
        ToggleMenu();
        Debug.Log("Pause menu ON");
    }
}
public void ToggleMenu()
{
    if (menu != null)
    {
        // Inverti lo stato attivo/inattivo del menu
        menu.SetActive(!menu.activeSelf);
    Debug.Log("TOGGLE MENU");
    }
}


Is it not working, or are you just rapidly toggling it?

it only works the first time it is pressed

"It works when I set a breakpoint" - that's a strong indicator for a race condition. Do you depend on something to happen in a specific order?

Why are there two ifs ? If both resolve to true, you will toggle twice, when you only want to google once ( I would suppose ).

if i put the breakpoit on "if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.JoystickButton3) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.JoystickButton1))
{" works every time, if i start witout the breakpoint the menu appears just once

the two "if" is for multi-device, htc vive, oculus and other. but i have problem only with oculus

possibly problematic that you call menu.SetActive multiple times in a sequence (within Update, then again within ToggleMenu) + use a state member of menu as input.

ok I tried but unfortunately it didn't work

menu, amenu, imenu, smenu - it's diffcult to read these and differentiate between them. Do yourself a favour and use better variable names, it's difficult to see the differences between all the if (menu.activeSelf == true && *menu.activeSelf == true)

Update function will be called each frame so when user press the button, ToggleMenu function will be called continuous until user released the button. Breakpoint will prevent ToggleMenu call several times. You can check reference my code to fix it:
if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Menu) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)) && !menuPressed)
{
    ToggleMenu();
    Debug.Log("Pause menu ON");
    menuPressed = true; // Mark as pressed
}
else if (menuTogglePressed && (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Menu) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.T)))
{
    menuPressed = false; // Reset the flag when the key is released
}

